# c++ compiler for windows mobile

Tags: c++, windows, compiler-construction, mobile

Well I was curious about this and searched for a while but couldn't find anything really, but maybe someone there got an answer...

I would like to compile code **ON** my windows mobile 6, and also probably be able to run it aftewards (note that I'm saying ON not FOR). Does something like that even exist?
I mean, 600 MHz CPU on my TOPAZ could handle this task already so maybe some fanatic developed it. I'd be glad if it could even compile some visual code (I think there isn't way to display command line on WM), but I got DOS emulator so it could handle also pretty basic code.

And just BTW if there would be(or not) something for Windows Mobile what about other devices? Something based on JAVA probably. I could emulate that maybe, but native would be prefered.

**EDIT:**

Well and something just came to my mind reading comments. If I am able to run something under DOS is there any reasonable compiler working in DOS? Something like old command line compiler would maybe do the trick...

And yes the reason for this. Well I'm not much into scripting languages, so this is just a try before I'll got to learn them anyway, but it would be great to create some simple and bruteforce solving programs on-air, and possibly much more use to it.

Thanks ;)

Comment: There's a fairly heavy "why?" that's not being addressed in this question.  Developing code with an emulator is just so much simpler.  Consider a scripting language.

Comment: I'm reasonably sure no such thing exists for any version of Windows Mobile. Yes, the CPU could handle it -- the obvious shortcomings would be the I/O (Keyboard, screen, etc.) I don't believe Windows Mobile supports a console mode either, so porting gcc (for example) would be non-trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at PowerGCC - port GCC to PocketPC platform. It's pretty complicated "quest" to install it.
http://www.mpcclub.com/wiki/index.php/CPrograms#Install_a_C_environment_on_PocketPC_.28compiler_etc..29

cke - IDE for mobile platform
http://www.animaniak.com/cke/cke_main.asp

Comment: yeah it looks a bit complicated but if I get it running it might be just what I'm looking for!